# Why is "toFixed" stopping my function from being ran multiple times?

Tags: javascript, tofixed

I am trying to make a money counter, where every time you click, it increases your amount of "money" by 1 dollar. However, I want the display of money to always show 2 decimal places. When I use toFixed(2) to fix this, it makes it so the function can only be run once, and not again until the page is refreshed.

I've tried removing the toFixed part of the code, and it functions properly, but it does not display the decimal places like I would like it to.

```
let money = 0;
let mpc = 1;
let moneySuffix = "";

function coinClick() {
    money = money + mpc;
    money = money.toFixed(2);

    if (money >= 1000) {
        moneySuffix = " thousand";
    } else if (money >= 1000000) {
        moneySuffix = " million";
    } else if (money >= 1000000000) {
        moneySuffix = " billion";
    } else if (money >= 1000000000000) {
        moneySuffix = " trillion";
    } else if (money >= 1000000000000000) {
        moneySuffix = " quadrillion";
    } else {
        moneySuffix = "";
    }

    document.querySelector("#totalMoney").innerHTML = "$" + money + moneySuffix;
}
```

I expected for it to display 1.00 after one click, and 2.00 after two clicks, etc. However, it displays 1.00 after one click, and then the number cannot be increased again.

Comment: Check the console, you most definitely have errors there. You change `money` from a numeric type to a string, and `toFixed` doesn't exist there, thus you'd get an error when calling it.

Comment: `money = +money + mpc;`

Comment: Side note: Your logic for the suffix will not work the way you intend. It will always be nothing, or "thousand", since a quadrillion will always be larger than 1000. Reverse the order of your if statements and it should work fine.

Comment: Question: If the number is `1234567`,  then you want the misleading output of `$1234567.00 million`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method [Number.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) returns a string, so you are converting an initially numeric type to string, and this can lead to errors on subsequent `clicks`, since you will try to execute `toFixed()` on a string. If you are trying to show the number to the user with two decimals, then apply the method only on the section of the code that will show it to the user:

```
let money = 0;
let mpc = 1;
let moneySuffix = "";

function coinClick()
{
    money = money + mpc;

    if (money >= 1000 && money < 1000000) {
        moneySuffix = " thousand";
    } else if (money >= 1000000 && money < 1000000000) {
        moneySuffix = " million";
    } else if (money >= 1000000000 && money < 1000000000000) {
        moneySuffix = " billion";
    } else if (money >= 1000000000000 && money < 1000000000000000) {
        moneySuffix = " trillion";
    } else if (money >= 1000000000000000) {
        moneySuffix = " quadrillion";
    } else {
        moneySuffix = "";
    }

    // Note, we use toFixed() just here, but we don't change the numeric type
    // of the variable money.
    document.querySelector("#totalMoney").innerHTML = "$" + money.toFixed(2) + moneySuffix;
}
```

Note that also I have made changes to the `if-else` block to work correctly, and as a side note, take in presence that there is a limit: [Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)